# Creating a visual graph from input data

Tags: python, graph, visualization

I have a text file like this:

```
A
B
A
C
A
B
B
C
...
```

and I would like yo create a directed graph line by line. I would like to know if there is any library that can help on that.

Comment: your format is odd, can you define it a bit more? in python, there is networkx or igraph that are both great graph libraries. igraph is a bit harder to use but faster

Comment: That means, A connects to B, B connects to A, A connects to C and ...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I did not get your question right here you have some doc on how to plot a graph using igraph: [igraph tutorial](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#layouts-and-plotting). It shows more options on personalisation.

a thing to remember with igraph is that edges and vertices are linked to indices.
Here a quick example

```
import igraph

g = igraph.Graph() # we create an empty graph object

vertices_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D"] # we have here four vertices
g.add_vertices(4, attributes={"name": vertices_names})  # we had the vertices with a name attribute

edges = [[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]] # here we define the edge 0 is A 1 is B etc...

g.add_edges(edges)

g.vs["label"] = g.vs["name"]
layout = g.layout("kk")
igraph.plot(g, layout = layout)
```

Comment: as a comment, I would say that for high-quality graph visualisation I use external tools such as cytoscape for small-medium graph and gephi for a large one.